# Mandrill UNSUB merge tag not adding to blacklist

Tags: mandrill

I put a merge tag in my email:

```
<a href="*|UNSUB:http://x.com/unsub.html|*">Click here to unsubscribe.</ a>
```

It is correctly turned into a link that takes me to the landing page, but the email recipient is not added to the blacklist.
I also see the **List-Unsubscribe** header in the email even though I don't explicit add that - expected.

The link is like (truncated):

```
http://mandrillapp.com/track/click/30738968/mandrillapp.com?p=eyJzIjoiRk96QWtzUE03NE5ROXFuWFpCX3RpUkJuNndz
```

Comment: Please provide more details or atleast put up the question with screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was patience.  It took several hours to register on the black list.